# Which parts of Memory can Swap Support

Tags: memory, swap

For this question, "swap" does not include RAM and only refers to the configured space on the disk.

According to, http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html, a program's memory usage consists of text, data, bss, stack, and heap.

The stack has a soft limit which can be removed. Let's assume it is removed. It is known the swap can augment heap ([Can swap space accomodate single process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202373/can-swap-space-accomodate-single-process)). Can swap also support or augment the stack, text, data, and bss parts of the memory required by a process, should RAM become insufficient?

Comment: Tosh the link is broken.